# wordpress update_user_meta inexplicably not working

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Somehow, my login plugin is not setting the user display_name at registration. Since I use the display_name meta in my profile page, I am trying to make sure that it is set to some value. Here is the code:

```
<?php global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();


if ("" == trim($display_name)) {        
    $result = update_user_meta($user_id, 'display_name', $user_identity);
    if ($result == false) {
        echo "hi";
    }
}
?>
```

This code results in "hi". I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

It's `user_ID`, with caps. I think this might be the problem.

All variables returned by `get_currentuserinfo()` must be declared as globals. You either declare all of them or use `$current_user`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Try to declare the following variables as globals too: $display_name, $user_ID, $user_identity. Otherwise, use the already declared `$current_user` one as specified here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$user_id`, try using `$current_user->ID`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that display_name isn't available in update_user_meta.

To set the user display name at registration you'll instead you'll need to use pre_user_display_name as described here: [How to Use pre_user_display_name to set the display name](http://geektamin.com/blog/533/why-update_user_meta-display_name-doesnt-work-and-how-to-use-pre_user_display_name-instead/)